# using **kwargs in __init__

Tags: python, init, keyword-argument

I am running into the following problem:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self,firstname, lastname, **kwargs):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

student1 = Student("John" ,"Johnson" , {"Nationality": "Middle-Earth" , "Sports": ["volleyball","skiing"]})
```

I want to be able to create students that all have a first and a last name, but only some have information about nationality or sports.  (Actually I am experimenting with reconstructing objects from json files.)
So I want to turn kwarg key into instance variable names, like this pseudo-code

```
for key,value in kwargs:
   self.key = value
```

the above is pseude-code, but is there a way to do this in correct python?  in other words: derive instance variable names from kwargs rather than all predefined.

I know this won't result in errorproof code etc..., but I want to know if it can be done.

Comment: Are you sure you only want to set certain attributes some of the time, on your objects? It's awkward to figure out if an attribute exists. It's a lot easier if you can assign some default value, like `None`, if there's no useful data.

Comment: It's *somewhat* of a bad idea. Part of the idea of defining a class is that you *know* what attributes an instance will have without having to resort to introspection. Better to assert that an instance *will* have attributes `Nationality` and `Sports`, but the value of each could be `None` or empty list or the like if no value is explicitly given at instantiation.

Comment: (That said, using `**kwargs` for a class that supports cooperative inheritance via `super` is a *very* good idea, though for very different reasons.)

Comment: Agree with the comments.  I know this code won't win a Nobel prize, but my questions was more about the concept.  Knowing how this can be done, could be useful if there are many attributes.  there I would rather use **kwargs than dozens op parameters in my __init__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in the `__init__` method:

```
for k, v in kwargs.items():
    setattr(self, k, v)
```

However, this is not recommended for code than needs to be reusable. If there are typos in the keyword parameters, you won't catch them. Code-checking tools such as pylint will not recognize class attributes initialized like that. You can use the following pattern (especially if there are many kewyord arguments):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, **kwargs):
        self.firstname = str(firstname)
        self.lastname = str(lastname)
        self.nationality = None
        self.sports = None

        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self, k, v)
            else:
                raise KeyError(k)

# this works
s=Student('John', 'Doe', sports=['socker'])

# this will give an error
s=Student('John', 'Doe', sprots=['socker'])
```

Comment: Great solution.  the extra check `if k in self.__dict__` is very useful.  makes it more errorproof and still allows the use of **kwargs rather than passing all the named arguments one by one to __init__

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass unpacked kwargs to `Student` and use `setattr(object, name, value)` to set the values:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self,firstname, lastname, **kwargs):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

        for (k,v) in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

student1 = Student("John" ,"Johnson" , **{"Nationality": "Middle-Earth" , "Sports": ["volleyball","skiing"]})
print(student1.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
{'lastname': 'Johnson', 'Sports': ['volleyball', 'skiing'], 'firstname': 'John', 'Nationality': 'Middle-Earth'}
```

Comment: Far more natural than unpacking a dict like that would be to use actual keywords, like `Nationality="Middle-Earth"` and so on. And if there are a finite number of optional arguments, making the `__init__` method name them and give them sensible defaults (like `None`) is probably better than using `kwargs` anyway.

Comment: setattr() is exactly what I was looking for.  The reason why I can't use Nationality="Middle-Earth" is that I get a dictionary from a json file in the.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend stating up front what attributes an instance can have, and using sentinel values like `None` to indicate the lack of a "real" value over eliminating the attribute altogether. For example:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self,firstname, lastname, nationality=None, sports=None):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.nationality = nationality
        self.sports = [] if sports is None else sports
```

Then

```
student1 = Student("John" ,"Johnson" , "Middle-Earth" , ["volleyball","skiing"])
student2 = Student("Bob", "Smith", nationality="Australia")  # No sports
student3 = Student("Alice", "Doe", sports=["hockey"])  # No nationality
```

If you want to parse JSON which may have key names that don't match your parameter names, define a class method to do the processing to get appropriate arguments. For example,

```
@classmethod
def from_dict(cls, data):
    firstname = data["FirstName"]
    lastname = data["some last name"]
    nationality = data.get("Nationality")
    sports = data.get("Sports", [])
    return cls(firstname, lastname, nationality, sports)
```

Then

```
student = Student.from_dict({'FirstName': 'John', 'some_last_name': 'Doe',})
```